# How to use python in command line in another directory

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, pythonpath

I am trying to run python in my command line. The location of my python directory is

```
C:\Users\Samarth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
```

Now i want to run python in a different directory named

```
C:\Users\Samarth
```

I have set the PYTHONPATH environment variable and added it to user variables and system variables and also used the 'set path = %PYTHONPATH%'command in the command line. But when i try to use the 'python' command, i get the usual error message 'python is not recognized as an internal command or and external command'. I also tried running the command prompt as an administrator.
NOTE: The command line is running in the

```
C:\Users\Samarth
```

directory.

How can i use python in this directory? Also, is it necessary to place my scripts in the 'Scripts' folder?

Comment: The installer gave you the option to modify the environment variables. It will add the installation directory and "Scripts" subdirectory to `PATH` and ".PY" file extension to `PATHEXT`. The py.exe launcher should already be in `PATH`, so you can also run `py`, or `py -3.7`, or `py -3.7-32`.

Comment: Also, please read the documentation. Nothing in the definition of [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) suggests it has anything to do with running the `python` command. It's for extending `sys.path` with packages in arbitrary locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `C:\Users\Samarth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32` to your `PATH` environment variable.

The shell will look for executables in all the locations mentioned in `$PATH` when running a command.

If the python executable location is part of `PATH`, it should be accessible from any other location.